# Agora video call not working in Web SDK when user try to connect from Android App

Tags: android, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-implementation

```
    eventHandler = object : IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
        override fun onJoinChannelSuccess(channel: String?, uid: Int, elapsed: Int) {
            Log.d("VideoCall1", "channel:$channel,uid:$uid,elapsed:$elapsed")
            openScreen(ScreenType.VIDEO_CALL_SCREEN)
        }

        override fun onUserJoined(uid: Int, elapsed: Int) {
            Log.d("VideoCall1", "onUserJoined:$uid")
            viewModel.onUserJoined(uid)
        }

        override fun onUserOffline(uid: Int, reason: Int) {
            Log.d("VideoCall1", "onUserOffline:$uid")
            viewModel.onUserOffline(uid)
        }
    }
    rtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(this, AppConstants.AGORA_APP_ID, eventHandler)

    rtcEngine.apply {
            enableVideo()
            setClientRole(0)
           // setChannelProfile(Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION)
            joinChannel(token, channelName, "", userId.toInt())
        }
```

Mobile user able to see web user but web user not able to see mobile user. Also I am getting callback of `onUserJoined` when web user joined channel.

I am using **io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:3.5.0** and it works with
https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1-Web/

Anyone have a suggestion or idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this took me hours of try and error to figure out a solution. I believe it's a bug in AgoraRTC but I didn't dive deep to figure out what's happening. Anyway, the hack I found goes like this:

In the Agora RTM script on the Web side, use a string uid while logging in:

```
this.client.login({ uid, token }); // uid had to be a string in my case
```

However, it says in the [Agora documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/help/integration-issues/string#:%7E:text=To%20ensure%20smooth%20communication%2C%20all%20the%20users%20in%20a%20channel%20should%20use%20the%20same%20type%20of%20user%20account%2C%20that%20is%2C%20either%20the%20integer%20user%20ID%2C%20or%20the%20string%20user%20account.) that the types of uid must match on web and mobile, since you are using int on mobile you might need to use an int on the web too, however when I tried to use an int, the login method threw an invalid uid type error!

But then again, it only worked if when joining the channel I supply the AgoraRTC client join method a null uid:

```
// uid (last argument) must be null
client.join(options.appid, options.channel, options.token, null);
```

It also works if the uid in the join function is the same uid in the login function but parsed to a number, but it doesn't if both are strings. And it also doesn't work if both are numbers, the login method throws an invalid uid variable type error...

Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue since it's a very weird error with no answers found anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: Thank you, for your effort but this problem solve from web side

Comment: @HeetChangela can you please post solution as well.